# Display 3D using HelixToolkit

Tags: c#, 3d

Is there any code that I can use to display my 3D model ? , I Tried using HelixToolkit but i don't know how to use it, can anyone show me with a piece of code to just load a 3D Obj file

Comment: Could you show some/any code that you've tried to use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've used `Nuget` to download the Helix3D libraries, but if you download the source code from `GitHub` then this includes an extensive `ExampleBrowser` application that gives guidance of how to use Helix3D

[Helix3D on GitHub](https://github.com/helix-toolkit)

My application is structured as follows:

XAML

```
    <h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="HelixViewport3D" ShowViewCube="False">
        <h:DefaultLights/>
        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="MyModel"/>         
    </h:HelixViewport3D>
```

C#

```
  var scene = new Model3DGroup();
  scene.Add(Load3dObject(@"C:\filename.obj"));
  MyModel.Content = scene;
```

Which calls this helper function `Load3dObject`I created to help clean up the code.

```
    private Model3D Load3dObject(string objName)
    {
        var reader = new ObjReader();
        var modelGroup = reader.Read(objName);
        return modelGroup;
    }
```

Comment: Yes I am using NuGet , Can you be more Specific .. how can i use your Code ( Thanks )

Comment: How familiar are you with WPF in general?

Comment: I am beginner in using WPF but I have learned how to add a 3d Model using the following code :
            ModelVisual3D device3D = new ModelVisual3D(); 
            device3D.Content = Display3d(MODEL_PATH);  
            viewPort3d.Children.Add(device3D); 

I want to know how can i add texture to my 3d model